# How to store Stanza Span in MongoDB collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, stanford-nlp

I am trying to add a list of dictionaries (whose name is `stanzanerlist`) like the following:

```python
stanzanerlist = [{
  "text": "Harry Potter",
  "type": "PER",
  "start_char": 141,
  "end_char": 153
}, {
  "text": "Hogwarts",
  "type": "LOC",
  "start_char": 405,
  "end_char": 413
}, {
  "text": "JK Rowling",
  "type": "PER",
  "start_char": 505,
  "end_char": 515
}]
```

as a field in a MongoDB document in a collection.

I am inserting the whole document as follows with `stanzanerlist` as the last item in `mongodocument`:

```python
mongodocument = {
        "_id": urlid,
        "source": sourcename,
        "stanzadoc": stanzadoc.to_serialized(),
        "stanzaver": stanzaver,
        # "timestamp": datetime.now(tzinfo),
        "timestamp": datetime.now(
            tz=pytz.timezone(cfgdata["timezone"]["name"])
        ),
        "stanzanerlist": stanzanerlist,
    }
try:
        mdbrc = mdbcoll.insert_one(
            mongodocument
        )  # insert fails if URL/_ID already exists
        return mdbrc
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        # manage the record update
        print(f"Article {urlid} already exists!")
```

but while all other fields work well, the addition of `stanzanerlist` gives the following error:

```python
cannot encode object: {
  "text": "Harry Potter",
  "type": "PER",
  "start_char": 141,
  "end_char": 153
}, of type: <class 'stanza.models.common.doc.Span'>
```

and I'm not able to understand if and how  I could achieve that addition.

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question?

Comment: NOTHING :( Trying to edit but get "Too many pending edits" :( Sorry

Comment: Doesn't that need to be three separate Mongo documents?  And IS `stanzanerlist` actually a list of `Span` objects, and not just a dictionary, as you have said?

Comment: Well ideally those are named entities that belong to one document, so I'd like to have them in that document meaning those are a list of named entities found in that document.

Comment: OK, but are they actually objects, as the error says?  If so, you need to convert them to a list of dictionaries before passing it to Mongo.

Comment: type(stanzanerlist) is a list, type(stanzanerlist[0]) is <class 'stanza.models.common.doc.Span'>

Comment: Does this get you closer? [`"stanzanerlist": [stan.to_dict() for stan in stanzanerlist]`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/data_objects.html#span)

Comment: @rickhg12hs that's exactly what I needed to do!!! Thanks a lot. So the insight is that I needed to transform that list of Span objects, which looked like a list of dictionaries to dictionaries, right? If you want to post this as an answer I'll happily accept and upvote it. Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pymongo` doesn't natively know how to convert `<class 'stanza.models.common.doc.Span'>` types to an acceptable BSON data type.

You could *"teach"* `pymongo` how to do the proper conversion/encoding using a custom [`bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/codec_options.html#bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder) and then `pymongo` would automatically perform type conversions as it does for other types.  Or, you could do the conversion/encoding each time yourself before storing the `Span` in your MongoDB collection.

Fortunately, Stanford NLP Stanza has convenience methods for type conversions.  [`<class 'stanza.models.common.doc.Span'>`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/data_objects.html#span) has a `to_dict` method that will convert the type to type `Dict`, which `pymongo` does know how to encode.

So, in your code snippet, you could change the `mongodocument` assignment of `"stanzanerlist"` to:

```python
"stanzanerlist": [stan.to_dict() for stan in stanzanerlist]
```

... and then each `<class 'stanza.models.common.doc.Span'>` will be converted to a `Dict` and `pymongo` should be able to store it.